# Django meta admin ordering - Excluding grammatical articles

Tags: python, django, admin

I currently have this chunk of model code:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    num_pages = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher)
    publication_date = models.DateField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["title"]
```

If I have a book title called '*The Fry Chronicles*' or '*A Hitchhikers Guide to the Galaxy*' (for example), is there a way to get Django to ignore those short articles (*an, a, the* etc.) before the word within the admin interface, and just order the results by the words that follows the article?

To take it a step further, maybe there is a way to lay out the results like this...

- Fry Chronicles, The
- Hitchhikers Guide to the Galaxy, A

As to move the article to the end of the book title?

Could anybody propose a solution to the above two issues?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible without hacking internal django admin code.

You can however do a little trick if some redundancy is not a problem. Have additional field in Book that represents title for ordering (like `clean_title`) and the use `ordering` [attribute](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.ordering) in admin.

Answer (score 2):

You could try,

```
class Book(models.Model):
    displayed_title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ordered_title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.displayed_title

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["ordered_title"]
```

And just make sure that you are parsing `ordered_title` before you store it.

Answer (score -1):

Don't know if this is working....untested...just an idea to keep in mind that django is just python...I hope that helps to get you to the right track!?!

```
def splitter(title):  
    list_title=[]
    a = split(title)    
        for word in a:
            if len(word) > 3: # With this you filter "a" "the" etc. but not "Bob" etc.!!
               word.append(list_title)
    return list_tile


class Meta:
    ordering = splitter(title) # not sure if this is working....
```

Comment: Ordering doesn't work that way. You need to specify a tuple/list with fields, not a function. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#ordering